# Installing CoverGloobus

Tags: 10.10, ppa, compiling, covergloobus

Is there any easier way to install Covergloobus 1.6 in Ubuntu 10.10 ? PPA doesnt work , tried to compile it but failed , are there any other ways??

Comment: Why doesn't the PPA work? What error do you get?

Comment: it seems that they do not have a repository for Maverick , yet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Lucid packages from the PPA work in Maverick, but you have to download them manually.

Here are the direct download links from the [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~gloobus-dev/+archive/covergloobus/+packages):

- [covergloobus_1.7-4_i386.deb [image]](https://edge.launchpad.net/~gloobus-dev/+archive/covergloobus/+files/covergloobus_1.7-4_i386.deb)
- [covergloobus_1.7-4_amd64.deb [image]](https://edge.launchpad.net/~gloobus-dev/+archive/covergloobus/+files/covergloobus_1.7-4_amd64.deb)

Comment: thanks =) i found these earlier and it works on Maverick although its for Lucid

Answer (score 4):

**CoverGloobus** 1.6 "WOW!" lives up to its name – an awesome application for displaying cover art and lyrics on your desktop

**PPA**

Enter a terminal (Applications->Accessories->Terminal) and use:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gloobus-dev/covergloobus
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install covergloobus
```

**Tar**

Download from [the website](http://launchpad.net/covergloobus/1.6/1.6stable/+download/covergloobus_1.6.tar.gz), extract, enter the directory and run:

```
./autogen.sh && make && sudo make install
```

Comment: To compile the code remember to install the autogen.sh dependencies using "sudo apt-get install autoconf"

Answer (score 1):

As said before, there is no maverick ppa. But you can use the lucid ppa, if you prefer to install by ppa rather than .deb, and also to be updated:
in a terminal run

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then copy and paste the following at the end of the file:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/gloobus-dev/covergloobus/ubuntu lucid main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/gloobus-dev/covergloobus/ubuntu lucid main
```

Finally, update sources and install:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install covergloobus
```

Answer (score 1):

Addendum to @hhlp: CoverGloobus 1.6 "WOW!" lives up to its name ...

**TAR**

Better use *checkinstall*, this resutls in a .deb package. If you like to revert to a previous version, be sure to first uninstall the old version (sudo apt-get remove covergloobus):

```
sudo apt-get install checkinstall
./autogen.sh && checkinstall make install
```