# How to disable gtk-theme in covergloobus?

Tags: 11.04, covergloobus, titlebar

I installed covergloobus in Ubuntu 11.04 Natty Narwhal. But when I start covergloobus. It is handled like an opened appliciation.

There is still a titlebar. How can I disable the gtk-theme ?

[image: Covergloobus]

Comment: I was about to post this :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Install **CompizConfig
  SettingsManager**

  `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`
- Launch it by searching from the dash
  in **Unity**, or **Preferences >
  CompizConfig Settings Manager** in
  **Ubuntu Classic**.
- Navigate to the **Window Decoration**
  tab.

[image]

- Add a new rule to **Decoration
  Windows**.

[image]

- Enter the value `Covergloobus.py`,
  and tick the **Invert** box.

[image]

- Click **Add**.

Comment: Worked for me!!!

Comment: this only works for me if I install and enable the "widget layer" compiz plugin (compiz-plugins-extra)

Answer (score 2):

I followed the following [instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9070/installing-covergloobus) to download the v1.6 source code, compiled and installed.  Using this method, there are no theme issues in the default natty install.

Answer (score 1):

In CompizConfig Settings Manager, click **Window Decoration** under the effects category. Enter the following text into the fields Decoration windows and Shadow Windows:

```
!(class=covergloobus)
```

Seems to work for me.

EDIT: Does NOT work for me. With this on, anytime I click something on the panel, Unity restarts. I suppose you can try it, anyway, it is reversible.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install **ConpizConfig Settings
   Manager**

   ```
   sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
   ```
2. Launch it from **Preferences >
   CompizConfig Settings Manager**,
   and configure your **Window
   Decoration** as shown:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The covergloobus 1.7 installed from a .deb file.

[image]